# Django reverse lazy url. Need to add to url some filters

Tags: python, django

I have `reverse_lazy('main:rooms')`. Need to add filter after url. Example **rooms/?status=free**

How to add my additional  url parametrs to **reverse_lazy**?

Comment: You don't, you append it to the result of the call to reverse().

Comment: how to realize it?